# react native nested fetches

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I have to render a list of cards with data. At first step I have to fetch a configured list of IDs. This fetch is relatively fast. And then in the second step I'm fetching the detailed information's for each ID. This second fetch is relatively slow, therefore each card with detailed information has an own spiner.

The IDs and detailed infos are coming from different, asynchronous data sources.

What is the best approach to do that?

I tried to fetch the ID list using redux from container's ComponentDidMount. And then in ComponentDidMount of each Card I'm initiate fetch of detailed informations for each ID. This works.

In the state-object I have then an object which holds all infos like this

````
```
{
   "accounts": {
        "id1": { "detailedInfo": "Datailed Info 1", fetching : false },
        "id2": { "detailedInfo": "Datailed Info 2", fetching : false },
        "id3": { "detailedInfo": "", fetching : true },
        ...
   },
   fetching : false,
   error : false
}
```
````

The problem is, if I change one of entries in accounts-map, the whole list is re-rendered.

Is it possible to "bind" each card to it's own entry in props.accounts? So the card is re-rendered only if the particular detailed infos are changed?

This is container for the list

````
```
class BalancesContent extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func,
        fetching: PropTypes.bool,
        getAccounts: PropTypes.func,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.accounts.accounts.length == 0) {
            this.props.getAccounts();
        }
    }

    onRefresh() {
        this.props.getAccounts();
    }

    setState(newState) {
        console.log("bc new state", newState);
        super.setState(newState);
    }

    render() {
        const userCards = this.props.accounts.accounts?Object.keys(this.props.accounts.accounts).map((acc) =>
            <UserBalancesCard
                key={acc}
                account={acc}
                refreshing={false}
                balances={null} />
        ):null;

        return (
            <Content padder
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.props.accounts.fetching}
                        onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
                        title="Loading..."
                    />
                }>
                <BalancesSummary />        
                {userCards}        
            </Content>

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        accounts: state.accounts
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getAccounts: () => dispatch(AccountsActions.accountsRequest()),
    };
};
```
````

This is the Component with detailed informations

````
```
class UserBalancesCard extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func,
        fetching: PropTypes.bool,
        updateAccount: PropTypes.func,
    };

    getAccount() {
        return this.props.accounts.accounts[this.props.account];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("ubc did mount");
        const acc = this.getAccount();
        if (!(acc.balances.timestamp && acc.balances.timestamp > 0)) {
            this.props.updateAccount(this.props.account);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const acc = this.getAccount();
        console.log("render UBC", this.props.account);
        return (
            <Card style={styles.container}>
                <CardItem header>
                    <H1>{this.props.account}</H1>
                </CardItem>
                <BalancesCardItem balances={acc.balances} />
                <CardItem footer>
                    <Right>{acc.fetching && <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="small" />}</Right>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        accounts: state.accounts
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        updateAccount: (account) => dispatch(AccountsActions.balanceRequest(account),),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserBalancesCard);

```
````

Comment: show your jsx `<List />` please

Comment: Added JSX of container and car-component

Answer (score 0):

When you map a new list to your single components, you change the sate of those components and react starts rendering again. For example if you have a compoennt with `this.state.counter = 1` and you call `this.setState({counter: 1})` the component will rerender. To check, if the components values changed, you can implement the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Maybe try this in your `UserBalanceCard` component.

for example something like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.counter != this.props.counter) return true;
}
```

Comment: You are right! This is the solution. Sure, I can check it, whether the changes should be considered by the component. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help! If it works, don´t forget to upvote ;)